# Entity Framework 4 - How to inject logic in property setter?

Tags: entity-framework, propertychanged, change-notification

I have a property auto-generated from database in my edmx: ***Description***. I then create a "partial class" .cs file for the entity and add a read-only property: ***ShortDescription***. 
ShortDescription's getter simply processes Description (removes line feed, carriage return, etc).

How can I raise property change notification for ShortDescription on the setter of Description?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be a hack, but it can be done.

First, you need to override [`ReportPropertyChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.reportpropertychanging.aspx) and [`ReportPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.reportpropertychanged.aspx). Then check the parameter for the name of your property... in this case "Description". If it occurs, call `ReportPropertyChanging` or `ReportPropertyChanged` with the derived property name, in this case "ShortDescription". For any other value of the parameter, call the base version of `ReportPropertyChanging/Changed`.

**Edit:**  For example:

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanging(string property)
    {
        if (property == "Description")
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanging("ShortDescription");
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanging(property);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (property == "Description")
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged("ShortDescription");
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged(property);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I deserve any downvotes... for some reason MS sealed `ReportPropertyChanging/Changed`, but left `OnPropertyChanging/Changed` open. Use the code example, not the prose example.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to look at non-partial events! :)

Answer (score 3):

The methods are partial also, so in your partial class you can add code like this

```
 partial void OnDescriptionChanged()
  {
    OnPropertyChanged("ShortDescription"); 
  }
```